# Always says segmentation error,dont know where should i fix

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

This code is used to create array and sort it, my homeworks request is to calculate the time it runs. But seems this code doesn't work. When I type `$./sorting select v 20000` the shell says segmentation error, I dont know where I should fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* insertionSort(int * arr,int len){
    for (int i=1; i<len; i++){

        int x=arr[i];
        int j=i;

        while (j>0 && x<arr[j-1]){
            arr[j]=arr[j-1];
            j--;
        }

        arr[j]=x;
    }

    return arr;
}

int*  selectionSort(int* arr,int len){
    int pos=0;

    for (int i=0; i<len;i++){
        int minpos=arr[i];

        for (int j=i; j<len; j++){
            if (minpos>arr[j]){
                minpos=arr[j];
                pos=j;
            }

        }

        int x=arr[i];
        arr[i]=minpos;
        arr[pos]=x; 
    }

    return arr;
}

int* create_array(char category, int n){
    int *arr=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if (category=='s'){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
             arr[i]=i;
        }
    }
    else if (category=='v'){
        for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            arr[i]=i;
        }
    }
    else if (category=='r'){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=i;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             int j = rand() % n;   
             int t = arr[j];
             arr[j] = arr[i];
             arr[i] = t;
        }
    }
    else {return NULL;}

    return arr;
}

void main(char sort_algo,char category,int array_size){

    int *arr=create_array(category,array_size);

    if (&sort_algo == "select"){
        selectionSort(arr,array_size);
    }
    else{
        insertionSort(arr,array_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main(char sort_algo,char category,int array_size)` is a bizarre `main`. Is that your way of inputting "select v 20000"?

Comment: After you have corrected `main` to extract your parameters from `*argv[]` you will have a problem with `if (&sort_algo == "select")` which will *never* be true, since it is comparing pointers to objects in different places in memory. Use `strcmp()`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY    yep,th request is"Your program must take in three parameters (sort_algo ['select' | 'insert'], category ['s','r','v'], array_size
). For example, assuming your program is called ‘sorting’ to test the Selection sort on a random array of size 20000, we run (omitting the timecommand): 
./sorting select r 20000

Comment: @ProVayne You can take 3 parameters with `*argv[]` as well. Recommended reading: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/c-argc-argv

Comment: @WeatherVane It never show siegmentation error again, but seems this code never work, the running time is 0.00s since the length of array is 20000

Comment: Did you extract the integer value from `argv[3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify you main function, prototype must be as below if you want to take command line arguments:

> int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )

You must also consider WeatherVane's and Bence Kaulics's suggestions and read the stuff suggested for better understanding of concepts.

As a side note i have modified your code ( to bare minimum ) and it will run now. There are lots of improvement which can be done. Keep Learning !

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* insertionSort(int * arr,int len){
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<len; i++){

        int x=arr[i];
        int j=i;

        while (j>0 && x<arr[j-1]){
            arr[j]=arr[j-1];
            j--;
        }

        arr[j]=x;
    }

    return arr;
}

int*  selectionSort(int* arr,int len){
    int pos=0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len;i++){
        int minpos=arr[i];
        int j;
        for (j=i; j<len; j++){
            if (minpos>arr[j]){
                minpos=arr[j];
                pos=j;
            }

        }

        int x=arr[i];
        arr[i]=minpos;
        arr[pos]=x;
    }

    return arr;
}

int* create_array(char category, int n){
    int *arr=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if (category=='s'){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
             arr[i]=i;
        }
    }
    else if (category=='v'){
        int i;
        for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            arr[i]=i;
            //printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    else if (category=='r'){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            arr[i]=i;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
             int j = rand() % n;
             int t = arr[j];
             arr[j] = arr[i];
             arr[i] = t;
        }
    }
    else {return NULL;}

    return arr;
}
//main with command line arguments
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
//    argv[0]  argv[1]  argc[2]   argv[3]
//    sorting select      v        20000
    int num;
    sscanf (argv[3],"%d",&num);
    int *arr=create_array(argv[2][0],num);

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"select")==0){
        selectionSort(arr,num);
    }
    else{
        insertionSort(arr,num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just don't know why I still need use sscanf() when  I use *argv,. Can't I pass the input through the parameter of main?